# Can physical object hiding be quantified with entropy?

Tags: randomness, entropy

If it works in the virtual world, why can't the same principle work in the real world?

For example if you want to hide a private key, you need a virtual haystack to hide it inside, which is the entropy of it's random source.

So if we want to generate a 21.9 bit key we need to select one random one out of 4000000 possibilities.

The same way in the physical world if we have a 10 m^3 size room, but only 2m^3 area can be used to hide things, then if we were to hide a small object like a dice which is like 0.5 cm^2, then we have 4000000 possibilities, which would be 21.9 bits.

So could the real world hiding of object be quantified in the same way ( excluding the fact that our eyes have a wide vision range so it would be easier to find, but also we could not go through all possibilities as fast as a computer could)

Comment: Area, or volume, is not the right measure here - the units didn't even line up (2 m^3 / 0.5 cm^2 ~ a length is a result).  No matter how much volume is under my couch I can check it all in pretty much the same amount of time I can look in a very small jewelry box or on a much larger table.  Perhaps if you could enumerate all the possible distinct hiding places that would be a better measure.  There are 3 book shelves with 7 shelves/underneath (+21), 2 couches with 6 cushions each and 2 distinct covered floor areas (+14), a floor that can be fully viewed from 6 glances/standpoints (+6) etc etc.

Comment: When I look for stuff I can miss things while they are right in the field of view. Try to catch that in a formula I dare you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can quantify it with a probability distribution, yes—any probability distribution has an entropy.

Here's an analogy: Suppose a line of 256 people each flip a coin, and put it in their left hand if it comes up heads or their right hand if it comes up tails; then they close both hands in a fist.  If you can't watch them flipping and placing the coin in their hands, you can't tell which hand each person has the coin in.  The probability distribution on your *state of knowledge* about where the coins are has 256 bits of entropy.

The fact that it's people playing the which-hand game instead of a CPU storing a 256-bit key in a register in silicon is immaterial; **entropy is a property of the *probability distribution* characterizing your state of knowledge.**